# Automatically select values from listbox without selecting values

Tags: c#

Im working in c# using a windows form, i have a listbox and i want to get the values from the listbox without have to select the items and use (listbox.selecteditem) to get the values.

Is this possible?

I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lbsection.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lbsection.Items.SetSelect(i, True);
}
```

The error is

> Error  2:    The name 'True' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `true` not `True` is that the problem? have a try

Comment: Rayon Hall:- Welcome to stack. I think it is good to `post your responses` while somebody gave answers to your questions. If it is ok or any more updation or modification needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lbsection.Items.Count; i++)
{
   lbsection.Items.SetSelect(i, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lbsection.Items.SetSelect(i, true);
```

`true` and `True` are different hence c# is `case sensitive`

Answer (score 0):

Try likes

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lbsection.Items.Count; i++)
{
  lbsection.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```

or using `setSelected`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lbsection.Items.Count; i++)
{
  lbsection.SetSelected(i, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is case-sensitive; the boolean `true` is supposed to be lowercase. I think this is what you're trying to do (the code you supplied didn't compile):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbsection.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lbsection.SetSelected(i, true /*True*/);
}
```

But if you want to *retrieve* the values of each item in the listbox you can do this:

```
//This is not type-safe so use at your own risk
List<object> allItems = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in lbsection.Items)
{
    allItems.Add(item);
}
```